# How to output parquet file without csv or avro file?

Tags: java, csv, avro, parquet

I'm trying to write Parquet file directly (in this context, directly means without any intermediate files).

I have a workaround, output CSV or Avro file in first step and next convert it to Parquet file, but I want to write it without CSV, Avro or any other intermediate files.

`CsvWriteSupport` and `ConvertUtils` on [GitHub - Parquet/parquet-compatibility:](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-compatibility) allows me to convert any CSV to Parquet, but it does not support `GROUP` types. (source: [parquet-compatibility/CsvWriteSupport.java](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-compatibility/blob/master/parquet-compat/src/test/java/parquet/compat/test/CsvWriteSupport.java))

`AvroWriteSupport` is supported `GROUP` types (source: [parquet-mr/AvroWriteSupport.java](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/main/java/parquet/avro/AvroWriteSupport.java)), but I use it I must write schema file for Avro, convert it to a class file for Avro and it needs double time to convert (write to Avro and Avro to Parquet) ... it's not handy, I think.

So, I want to know how can I output Parquet file directly.

Is there any way to do that? or I have to write my original `WriteSupport` class?

Please give me your idea. Thanks.